# Bilinear mapping in Groups

Tags: group-theory, modules

Let $G$ be nilpotent group. Take finite order elements $x,y \in G$ and construct a subgroup $H = \langle x,y \rangle$ and $\gamma_1(H) = H, \gamma_i(H) = [\gamma_{i-1}(H),H]$. In order to prove $H$ finite, he has used some bilinear mapping from $H/\gamma_2(H) \times \gamma_{i-1}(H)/\gamma_i(H)$ to $\gamma_i(H)/\gamma_{i+1}(H)$ given by $a \gamma_2(H),b\gamma_i(H) \mapsto [a,b]\gamma_{i+1}(H) $ which induces an epimorphism $H/\gamma_2(H) \otimes \gamma_{i-1}(H)/\gamma_i(H) \longrightarrow \gamma_i(H)/\gamma_{i+1}(H)$. What is the meaning of bilinear map here? How is he translating group into module structure?

Comment: $H / \gamma_2(H)$ and $\gamma_{i-1}(H) / \gamma_i(H)$ are abelian groups, therefore Z-modules, so saying bilinear makes sense.

Comment: @SeanEberhard Thanks!